# Converting GeoJSON (or shapefile) data to FeatureLayer

Tags: geojson, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer, react

I am creating an interactive map using ArcGIS and React.

Presently, I am creating a `GeoJSONLayer`. However, I'm now trying to use a `UniqueValueRenderer` for some of the layers. [From the docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-UniqueValueRenderer.html), it appears the `UniqueValueRenderer` does not work with GeoJSON layers.

Is it possible to convert GeoJSON (or shapefile) data into a FeatureLayer and, if so, how do you do it?

Comment: here you have an example I made a while ago [usin-javascript-4-15-api-unable-to-creating-featurelayer-using-geojson-collectio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62120113/usin-javascript-4-15-api-unable-to-creating-featurelayer-using-geojson-collectio/62121396#62121396), there I fetch a geojson layer and display it as a feature layer .. for some reason I create the features by hand, I probably would try to use `fromJSON` methods

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is incorrect and will be fixed.
You can use `UniqueValueRenderer` just fine with `GeoJSONLayer`.
No need to convert the GeoJSON.